# how to work with Subversion

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2005

I have downloaded Collabnet Subversion for Windows and Tortoise Svn.

I have created a repository with Tortoise Svn. But When try to open Repo Browser and give path as svn:/// ..it doesnt point to my repository.

I have followed the steps indicated on [this website](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0807081&page=2).

Any other useful tutorials to view at ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is that you install [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). You don't really need to configure stuff with the command line and a text editor.

Answer (score 2):

[Agent SVN](http://www.zeusedit.com/agent) is a plug-in that implements the *MS-SCCI* so it will work with Visual Studio 2005.